# Sync code to async, without rewriting the function

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Basically I have synchronous code something similar to this:

```
def f(.):
   ...
def call(.):
   ..Some sync code..
   try:
      resp = f(..)
      ...some more transformations of resp...
          return ..
   except:
      ..Some error handling..

async def af(.):
    ...
```

Basically I want to dynamically alter the code of `call` so that it can call and await `af` function instead of `f`. Is there a way around this? I have found `syncit` on github, but it doesn't seem to be a solution to me as you have to rewerite the code to async first and then downgrade it to sync. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at `trio` https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html.  Notice in the first table, regular sync functions can't call async functions. However, `trio.run()` provides a way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

In `asyncio` world every coroutine can be executied either inside other coroutine (using `await`) or by event loop blocking call (using `run_until_complete()`).

You can't await coroutine inside regular function since this function's call would be blocking, while coroutine to be awaited needs blocking event loop execution. This is how `asyncio` designed to work.

If you ok with idea of your `call()` function being blocking and have access to `f()` implementation, you can execute coroutine inside `f()` runnning event loop:

```
async def af(.):
    ...

def f(.):
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   return loop.run_until_complete(af())

def call(.):
   ..Some sync code..
   try:
      resp = f(..)
      ...some more transformations of resp...
          return ..
   except:
      ..Some error handling..
```

If you don't have access to `f()` implementation, I don't believe you would be able to alter `call()` to await coroutines (without some ugly monkey-patching).

I think rewriting `call()` to be async would be only good option then.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two options mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

**Given**

```
import asyncio

import trio

from unsync import unsync
```

**Code**

*Option 1* - [`trio`](https://github.com/python-trio/trio)

Given sync code (`call`), call an async function via `trio` (`async_div`):

```
# Sync code
def call(x, y):
    """Return an awaited result."""
    try:
        resp = async_div(x, y)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Caught an exception."
    return resp
    

# Wrapper
def async_div(*args):
    """Return results from an async function."""
    return trio.run(_async_div, *args)


# Async code
async def _async_div(x, y):
    """Return an async result."""
    await trio.sleep(3)
    return x / y
```

*Option 2* - [`unsync`](https://github.com/alex-sherman/unsync)

Decorate the async code with `@unsync` and call the `result()`:

```
# Sync code
def call(x, y):
    """Return an awaited result."""
    try:
        resp = async_div(x, y).result()
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return "Caught an exception."
    return resp


# Async code
@unsync
async def async_div(x, y):
    """Return an async result."""
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return x / y
```

**Demo**

After the prescribed delay (3 secs), the results are the same:

```
call(0, 1)
# 0.0

call(1, 0)
# 'Caught an exception.'
```

**See Also**

Some additional resources:

- [docs](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) on `trio`
- [Talk Python interview](https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/167/simplifying-python-s-async-with-trio) with `trio` creator N. Smith for more details and his philosophy on asynchronous programming.
- [Python Bytes episode](https://pythonbytes.fm/episodes/show/73/this-podcast-comes-in-any-color-you-want-as-long-as-it-s-black) 73, item 6 on quick `unsync` details
- M. Kennedy's [webinar demo](https://youtu.be/F19R_M4Nay4?t=3515) on using `unsync` to speed up requests